# OpenLayers custom control in Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, openlayers

I'd like to create my own custom control using OpenLayers [`Control`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_control_Control-Control.html) base class within an Angular project.

I have a component that looks like this:

**control.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Host } from '@angular/core';

import { MapService } from '../map.service';
import { MapidService } from '../mapid.service';
import { Map } from 'ol';
import MyCustomControl from '../somewhere/my-custom-control';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-control',
  templateUrl: './control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./control.component.css']
})
export class ControlComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private mapService: MapService,
    @Host()
    private mapidService: MapidService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Get the current map
    const map: Map = this.mapService.getMap(this.mapidService.getId());
    const control = new MyCustomControl({});
    map.addControl(control);
  }

}
```

I'd like to create a class for my custom component, but, as it's the first time I have to do this in my Angular project (meaning, creating a class which is not a component with `ng g class mycustomclass`), I don't really know which would be the best way to do that.

My doubts in particular are:

1. In which folder should I place this new class?
2. Is it fine if I declare my new class with something like

```
export class MyCustomControl extends Control {
   constructor() {
      super({});
      ...
   }
}
```

in Angular (I'm used to do this in "plain" TypeScript projects), or is there a better way (another component)?

Comment: I am using const el = document.createElement(<defined element here>) to create the element for the control, and const control = new control({element: el}); map.addControl(control)

Comment: @unbe1987 did you find solution to this ??